# Firebase queryEqualToValue

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have the current Firebase Database structure.
[image: Firebase Database Structure]

I'd like to query all the true/false values.

Current code I have is;

```
let resultsRef = Database.database().reference().child("user_results").child(userID)
    let query = resultsRef.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: "false")
       query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

userID is "MyRQOZ..."

Printing out snapshot gives me nothing.  However, if I do

```
.queryLimited(toFirst: 1)
```

I get the snapshot I want.

```
["yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO84": false]
```

I believe on my ref I need to go one path further down.  But I don't know what id would be.

Answer (score 0):

You're only querying the first event

```
observeSingleEvent
```

Try

```
query.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

and add an if statement to catch the values

(Edit) Add this If Statement under the original bit of code that you have already, like this:

```
let resultsRef = Database.database().reference().child("user_results").child(userID)
let query = resultsRef.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: "false")
   query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in 
       if let trueOrFalse = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
               for (ke, value) in trueOrFalse {
                   if value as! String == "false" {
                       // 'ke' is now all of the keys where the value so you could do something like...
                       print(ke) //and it will give you the keys that have false as the value.
```

Comment: I changed my query to .queryLimited(toFirst: 1) just to see what came out of the snapshot. What I want is to get all the keys which have the value false next to them.

Comment: I have edited my answer, should work now for what you want